# DPAPI / MacOS-style Keyring for Linux or BSD?

Tags: security, password, password-store

Windows and Mac both have a handy way to secure data using the users' login credentials.

- The Data Protection API on Windows uses a symmetric key which is never stored in plain-text, and is encrypted using a key derived from the user's password. If the user logs in successfully, any program running as that user can encrypt or decrypt arbitrary data buffers; the functions to do this are part of the standard Windows API. If another user (even an admin) tries to decrypt that same data, or if the user's session was created without login credentials, DPAPI doesn't work. DPAPI keys are also permanently lost if the user's password is forcibly reset, either from within Windows, via Active Directory (LDAP), or by editing the disk.
- The Keychain feature on MacOS provides a structured data storage mechanism for passwords and other secrets (Windows has a similar credential store, built on top of DPAPI). The keychain application itself technically has its own authentication separate from the user login credentials, but by default, MacOS synchronizes the user's login and keychain passwords and automatically unlocks keychain access when the user logs in. If the user's password is forcibly reset, the old password will be needed to unlock the keychain.

This functionality is used by lots of software, both shipping with the OS (i.e. part of the distro) and in third-party packages large or small. It's very convenient, and I wish there was some equivalent on Linux.

*Is* there any equivalent functionality on Linux or non-Mac Unix(-like) systems? All the suggestions I've seen talk about things like GnomeKeychain or KWallet (which require manually unlocking after login, and are desktop-specific), third-party password managers with their own master passwords and generally not integrated with anything except browsers (like LastPass), or building something on top of GPG (which requires the user to enter a password, and has no simple way to protect or unprotect data programmatically). [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49205/dpapi-equivalent-on-linux) from Security.SE asks the same thing, but the answer ("No") is five years old now.

Comment: I don't understand your question very well. Do you want a pam module to decrypt your data automatically every time you login?

Comment: If "equivalent" means "single central functionality supported by virtually all programs", the answer is still "no".

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 Not "to decrypt it automatically"; the data should stay encrypted on disk at all times. Rather, imagine KWallet or similar, except that it unlocks (and thus the data can be decrypted, in memory, on demand) automatically when you log in, using the same credentials you used to log in.

Comment: @dirkt Not so much "supported by" as "available to" all programs, but otherwise, yes. I'm sure lots of software would continue using various other solutions for a long time, but it would be very nice to have something that provides equivalent functionality but doesn't depend on which desktop environment you install or require additional user interaction after login. I may take a crack at writing such a PAM module myself but wanted to avoid duplicating effort.

Comment: So basically a libopenssl warpper that provides an API return decrypted data everytime you call it with encrypted data and your private key (or symmetric key). If I'm right then I don't think PAM is related. PAM basically used for authentication and setup sessions, but obviously not all programs need that.

Comment: I'm confused now. Are you looking for a generally supported/integrated keyring (a place to securely store cryptographic keys), or a libopenssl wrapper? These two are very different things. Also note MacOS requires a password to unlock the keyring for changes. If you don't need "generally supported/integrated", there's a million ways to roll your own. If you need a particular existing keyring to be integrated into a a particular open-source application, the quickest way is probably to submit a patch...

Comment: Integrated keyring would be nice, but the key aspect is the automatic unlock when you log in and the ability of all programs running in your login session to take advantage of this unlock. A libopenssl wrapper would still need the keys supplied by the caller, right? So that doesn't qualify. Keyring functionality would be great, but I'd settle for DPAPI functionality: a simple pair of functions to encrypt and decrypt arbitrary data using your auto-generated, login-password-protected keys. Programs could store the encrypted data wherever they want

Comment: Didn't I just say that but you tell me "no, data should still be kept encrypted"?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I was responding more to dirkt than you, but no, that's not what I said. You said "... provides an API [to] return decrypted data every time you call it with your private key..." and that's not what I'm asking for. There are two things wrong. The minor one is that it's two APIs, one to encrypt and one to decrypt. The major one is that *the caller never supplies the key*; the key is stored encrypted ("wrapped") on disk when the user is logged out, and when the user logs in, the key is automatically unwrapped and stored in a daemon that processes the [de|en]crypt API requests.

Comment: @dirkt As a side note, MacOS "Keychain Access" GUI may demand your password when you want to see what it's storing, but by default *programmatic* access to the default ("login") keyring is available as soon as you log in, with no further password entry. That's what I'm looking for: a service, available through an API that any process (running as you) can call, that encrypts and decrypts data on command (no need to supply a key or password, so long as you are logged in). Whether it stores / retrieves the secrets (keychain) or simply returns the [en|de]crypted blob (DPAPI) doesn't matter much.

Comment: So your main point is you need to unlock (some part of) the keyring on login? That does sound like a custom PAM module (which you'd have to write), which will on login inform the keyring storage to open it up.

Answer (score 0):

[GNOME Keyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring) can do this, through PAM.

> GNOME Keyring is integrated with the user's login, so that their secret storage can be unlocked when the user logins into their session.

Answer (score -1):

No, there's no integrated solution.
What you mean is something that could link Luks file encryption, system login and desktop keyring solution (Gnome Keyring, KWallet, etc) altogether. Unfortunately this solution doesn't exists.